# Select an element that has another element anywhere inside

Tags: xpath

How do I select any node **a** that has node **b** anywhere inside it?

Given the following three XML documents:

```
<a>
    <b></b>
</a>
```

or

```
 <a>
    <c>
        <b></b>
    </c>
</a>
```

or

```
   <a/>
```

I want the **a** element in the first two documents to be selected.

Apparently, **a[//b]** is not a solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should try:

`//a[.//b]`

Answer (score 15):

```
a[descendant::b]
```

is more accurate and efficient than

```
a[.//b]
```

which is equal to

```
a[self::node()/descendant-or-self::node()/child::b]
```